# Fbconnect Share dialogue like web browser in ios app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook

I am making an ios app in which i want `share dialog box` as below picture. I am using fbconnect sdk. I googled about it but doesn't get anything for ios app. So any help would be appreciate
Thanks in advance[image]

Comment: yes, i also want same dialog box in my app. if its possible in fbconnect or in webview i really appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you got any kind of reference for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not there by default in iOS Facebook SDK. Though you can create your own dialog box. Open a dialog box like this where user can write whatever he wants to share. Add a picture button to attach an image too.

Have a button saying "on your own timeline". Clicking on which open a popup view like in the picture you have attached. If user selects

1) On your own timeline - send the request using as "me/feed"
2) on a friend's timeline - open a window showing the list of friends(which can be retrieved easily using fb SDK me/friends with the permission user_friends). User can select a friend and then send the request "FRIEND_ID/feed"
3) In a group - open a window showing list of groups user is connected to (which can be retrieved easily using fb SDK me/groups with the permission user_groups). User can select a group from it and then send the request "GROUP_ID/feed"
4) On your page - open a window showing list of pages user is admin of (which can be retrieved easily using fb SDK me/accounts with the extended permission manage_pages). User can select a group from it and then send the request "PAGE_ID/feed".

It is not that difficult to create your own dialog box.

Hope I helped.

Comment: Thanks for help, But it will too long process to achieve this whereas this share box in browser is so easy. So i think there is something we are missing out to got dialogue like browser

Comment: @Swati Nice answer. @Rahul There are list of thing which are much simpler to be developed in web browser. The problem you are facing is one of those things. There is no standard dialogue box in `FBConnect iOS SDK`, at least, as of now.

Comment: I have used the 1st two options in my application after searching a lot. I did not find any standard dialog box available. If you do get one, please share here.
@Viral thanks.

Comment: @SwatiWadhera : have you heared about `fbwebdialog` class of latest sdk?? Is it possible with this class?

Comment: dont know. have to see that